# Error running the server in cloud 9 ide rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cloud9-ide

When I try to run the server I get this lengthy error.

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.4 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:8080
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing': undefined method `before_avatar_post_process' for Podcast (call 'Podcast.connection' to establish a connection):Class (NoMethodError)
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/paperclip-4.3.1/lib/paperclip/validators.rb:67:in `create_validating_before_filter'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/paperclip-4.3.1/lib/paperclip/validators.rb:60:in `block in validate_before_processing'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/paperclip-4.3.1/lib/paperclip/validators.rb:58:in `each'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/paperclip-4.3.1/lib/paperclip/validators.rb:58:in `validate_before_processing'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/paperclip-4.3.1/lib/paperclip/validators/attachment_content_type_validator.rb:84:in `validates_attachment_content_type'
from /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/models/podcast.rb:9:in `<class:Podcast>'
from /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/models/podcast.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `block in load_file'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in `new_constants_in'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `load_file'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `require_or_load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in `load_missing_constant'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `const_get'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `block in constantize'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `each'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `inject'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `constantize'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:566:in `get'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:597:in `constantize'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.2/lib/devise.rb:287:in `get'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:81:in `to'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:76:in `modules'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:93:in `routes'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:160:in `default_used_route'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:70:in `initialize'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.2/lib/devise.rb:321:in `new'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.2/lib/devise.rb:321:in `add_mapping'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:224:in `block in devise_for'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:223:in `each'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:223:in `devise_for'
from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/routes.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:434:in `instance_exec'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:434:in `eval_block'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:412:in `draw'
from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:in `new'
from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:in `<main>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:8:in `require'
from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Do you have the string `before_avatar_post_process` somewhere in your code?

Comment: Is your database server running?

Comment: @Joe Can I see your `app/models/podcast.rb` file please?